# Анимация css3 движение звездочки по эллипсу svg

Tags: html, css, svg, анимация, css-animation

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать вращение звёздочки по синему кругу?

```css
.svg__hidden{
  display: none;
}
.ellipse {
  width: 550px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 500px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px #e5007e solid;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.ellipse svg {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  top: 160px;
  left: -140px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move linear infinite;
}
.ellipse:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateZ(20deg);
}
.ellipse:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateZ(30deg);
  border: 2px #006ab4 solid;
  z-index: 1;
}
.ellipse:nth-child(2) svg {
  transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
  animation-duration: 20s;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0deg) translateX(180px) rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(-30deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg) translateX(180px) rotateZ(-360deg) rotateY(-30deg);
  }
}
```

```html
        <svg width="0" height="0" class="svg__hidden">
            <symbol version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 95.000000 95.000000" id="star">
                <g transform="translate(0.000000,95.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" stroke="none">
                    <path d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"></path>
                </g>
            </symbol>
        </svg>

    <div class="a" style="position:relative;">
        <div class="ellipse">
        </div>
        <div class="ellipse">
            <svg class="intro__star-sm blink">
                <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При движении элемента по заданной траектории лучше вместо трансформаций CC3, использовать анимацию SVG: [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)
При этом варианте вам не нужно будет мучаться, подбирая многочисленные параметры и трансформации CSS.
Достаточно создать path траектории движения и объект будет четко двигаться по назначенному в теге `<mpath>` пути.

Если вам нужна будет какая-то другая траектория, то не возникнет никаких проблем, достаточно будет указать эту траекторию.

Прочтите пожалуйста комментарии в коде:

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 heght:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
 
       <!-- Синяя трасса движения -->
  <path id="traceB" d="M98 51c18-2 48 5 72 10a474 474 0 0 1 121 47l41 23c34 20 69 39 99 63 32 26 64 52 87 86 9 12 18 25 18 40 1 8-2 16-7 22-6 6-16 9-24 10-19 3-39 0-58-4-13-3-26-6-39-11a884 884 0 0 1-287-168c-17-15-32-32-45-52-4-6-9-17-10-25-6-27 7-37 32-41Z" id="path817" fill="none" stroke="#3589C4" stroke-width="2" />
         <!-- Розовая трасса движения  -->
 <path id="traceP" d="M75 89c65-11 133 5 197 21 53 13 104 36 153 62 37 19 76 40 106 70 9 9 17 20 21 32 4 16 2 25-11 34-9 6-20 9-31 10-47 5-96-3-143-13A764 764 0 0 1 95 186c-14-11-28-25-39-40-18-35-10-51 19-57Z" id="path819" fill="none" stroke="#ED50A7" stroke-width="2" /> 
               <!-- Звездочка -->
 <g id="star" transform="translate(0,-13) scale(0.03)"> 
 <path d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"/> 
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="14s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
     <mpath xlink:href="#traceB"  />
   </animateMotion>  
</g>

</svg>
</div>
```

Если нужно запустить звезду по другому эллипсу, достаточно вместо
`<mpath xlink:href="#traceB"  />` указать `id` другого эллипса `<mpath xlink:href="#traceP"`

Настройка размера звезды и её положения относительно эллипса

`<g id="star" transform="translate(0,-13) scale(0.03)">`

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 heght:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
 
       <!-- Синяя трасса движения -->
  <path id="traceB" d="M98 51c18-2 48 5 72 10a474 474 0 0 1 121 47l41 23c34 20 69 39 99 63 32 26 64 52 87 86 9 12 18 25 18 40 1 8-2 16-7 22-6 6-16 9-24 10-19 3-39 0-58-4-13-3-26-6-39-11a884 884 0 0 1-287-168c-17-15-32-32-45-52-4-6-9-17-10-25-6-27 7-37 32-41Z" id="path817" fill="none" stroke="#3589C4" stroke-width="2" />
         <!-- Розовая трасса движения  -->
 <path id="traceP" d="M75 89c65-11 133 5 197 21 53 13 104 36 153 62 37 19 76 40 106 70 9 9 17 20 21 32 4 16 2 25-11 34-9 6-20 9-31 10-47 5-96-3-143-13A764 764 0 0 1 95 186c-14-11-28-25-39-40-18-35-10-51 19-57Z" id="path819" fill="none" stroke="#ED50A7" stroke-width="2" /> 
               <!-- Звездочка -->
 <g id="star" transform="translate(0,-13) scale(0.03)"> 
 <path d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"/> 
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="14s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
     <mpath xlink:href="#traceP"  />
   </animateMotion>  
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Приложение будет адаптивно и  ***[кроссбраузерным](https://caniuse.com/?search=animateMotion)*** в современных браузерах, включая Edge MS/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду изучать

Comment: @МагомедДжалилов Пожалуйста, изучайте SVG, он для этого создан, чтобы работать с графикой. И сравните код, насколько он короче

Comment: Саша, я уточнить хотел , а если высоту не прописать разве она не станет автоматической ?

Comment: @Айболит станет и это будет эквивалентом 100%. Но всё же лучше указывать в относительных единицах   от окна браузера 100vw

Answer (score 3):

### Настройки и несколько совмещенных анимаций

`<g id="star" transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.03)">`
Если не смещать объект, то при `animateMotion` он будет двигаться по трассе соединяясь с ней верхним левым углом.

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 heght:auto;
 background:black;
}
#path {
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  fill:yellow;
  fill-opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
 
              <!-- Розовая трасса движения  -->
 <path id="traceP" d="M75 89c65-11 133 5 197 21 53 13 104 36 153 62 37 19 76 40 106 70 9 9 17 20 21 32 4 16 2 25-11 34-9 6-20 9-31 10-47 5-96-3-143-13A764 764 0 0 1 95 186c-14-11-28-25-39-40-18-35-10-51 19-57Z"  fill="none" stroke="#ED50A7" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  <!-- Звездочка -->
<g>
 <g id="star" transform="translate(0,0) scale(0.03)"> 
 <path id="path" d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"/> 
 </g>
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="14s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
      <mpath xlink:href="#traceP"  />
    </animateMotion>  
    
</g>

</svg>
</div>
```

Поднимаем звезду вверх, теперь она касается траектории нижним углом

`<g id="star" transform="translate(0,-28) scale(0.03)">`

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 heght:auto;
 background:black;
}
#path {
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  fill:yellow;
  fill-opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
 
              <!-- Розовая трасса движения  -->
 <path id="traceP" d="M75 89c65-11 133 5 197 21 53 13 104 36 153 62 37 19 76 40 106 70 9 9 17 20 21 32 4 16 2 25-11 34-9 6-20 9-31 10-47 5-96-3-143-13A764 764 0 0 1 95 186c-14-11-28-25-39-40-18-35-10-51 19-57Z"  fill="none" stroke="#ED50A7" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  <!-- Звездочка -->
<g>
 <g id="star" transform="translate(0,-28) scale(0.03)"> 
 <path id="path" d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"/> 
 </g>
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="14s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
      <mpath xlink:href="#traceP"  />
    </animateMotion>  
    
</g>

</svg>
</div>
```

Добавляем к анимации движения, анимацию вращения звезды, чтобы согласовать две анимации друг с другом необходимо добавить `additive="sum"`

```
 <!-- Анимация вращения звездочки -->
  <animateTransform   attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="1.8s"
   values="0;360" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum" />
```

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 heght:auto;
 background:black;
}
#path {
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  fill:yellow;
  fill-opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
          <!-- Розовая трасса движения  -->
 <path id="traceP" d="M75 89c65-11 133 5 197 21 53 13 104 36 153 62 37 19 76 40 106 70 9 9 17 20 21 32 4 16 2 25-11 34-9 6-20 9-31 10-47 5-96-3-143-13A764 764 0 0 1 95 186c-14-11-28-25-39-40-18-35-10-51 19-57Z"  fill="none" stroke="#ED50A7" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  <!-- Звездочка -->
<g>
 <g id="star" transform="translate(0,-28) scale(0.03)"> 
 <path id="path" d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"> 
        <!-- Анимация вращения звездочки -->
  <animateTransform   attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="1.8s" values="0;360" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
 
</g>
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="16s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
      <mpath xlink:href="#traceP"  />
    </animateMotion>  
    
</g>

</svg>
</div>
```

Две звездочки бегут по одной трассе, но они разного размера и имеют разные скорости

```css
.container {
 width:100vw;
 heght:auto;
 background:black;
}
#path {
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  fill:yellow;
  fill-opacity:1;
}
#path2 {
transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  fill:crimson;
  fill-opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" id="svg1"  viewBox="0 0 600 400">
          <!-- Розовая трасса движения  -->
 <path id="traceP" d="M75 89c65-11 133 5 197 21 53 13 104 36 153 62 37 19 76 40 106 70 9 9 17 20 21 32 4 16 2 25-11 34-9 6-20 9-31 10-47 5-96-3-143-13A764 764 0 0 1 95 186c-14-11-28-25-39-40-18-35-10-51 19-57Z"  fill="none" stroke="#ED50A7" stroke-width="2" /> 
  
  <!-- Звездочка -->
<g>
 <g id="star" transform="translate(0,-32) scale(0.035)"> 
 <path id="path" d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"> 
        <!-- Анимация вращения звездочки -->
  <animateTransform   attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="1.8s" values="0;360" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
 
</g>
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="16s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
      <mpath xlink:href="#traceP"  />
    </animateMotion>  
    
</g> 
        <!-- Звездочка2 (красная) -->    
<g>
 <g id="star2" transform="translate(0,-28) scale(0.03)"> 
 <path id="path2" d="M435 760 c-24 -112 -44 -185 -54 -194 -9 -7 -95 -31 -191 -51 -96
-21 -176 -38 -178 -40 -1 -1 79 -19 178 -40 112 -24 185 -44 194 -54 7 -9 31
-95 51 -191 21 -96 38 -176 40 -178 1 -1 19 79 40 178 24 112 44 185 54 194 9
7 95 31 191 51 96 21 176 38 178 40 1 1 -79 19 -178 40 -112 24 -185 44 -194
54 -7 9 -31 95 -51 191 -21 96 -38 176 -40 178 -1 1 -19 -79 -40 -178z"> 
        <!-- Анимация вращения звездочки -->
  <animateTransform   attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="1.4s" values="0;360" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
 
</g>
         <!-- Анимация движения звездочки по эллипсу   -->
  <animateMotion begin="0s" dur="12s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" additive="sum">
      <mpath xlink:href="#traceP"  />
    </animateMotion>  
    
</g>
```